# How to structure and run a multi-project dnx project?

Tags: dnx

I'm trying to get started with DNX but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to structure a multi-project project.

I have done some looking around and I found that it seems like most projects are structured like this:

```
global.json
src/
  ProjectA/
  ProjectA/project.json
  ProjectB/
  ProjectB/project.json
test/
  ProjectA.Test/
  ProjectA.Test/project.json
  ProjectB.Test/
  ProjectB.Test/project.json
```

From what I understand `global.json` points to the different projects and the different `project.json` files define the specific projects.

I have a similar structure except that I only have a single project named HelloWorld. This project is a console app. I plan on eventually adding more projects and add dependencies between them. For now I just want to be able to build them.

If I go to the `src/HelloWorld/` directory and run `dnx run` it all works. The issue is that I don't want to have to go to that directory. I'd rather be in the root of my project (the directory containing `global.json`).

How can I run my console app project without having to be in the directory of that specific project? I'd like to be able to do it with something as simple as `dnx run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the project you want to run, to `dnx` fairly easily.  Unfortunately for your use case it won't make it much easier (although you always make a .cmd/.sh/.ps1 file to do the command for you).

The command would simply be:

`dnx -p ./src/HelloWorld run`

the -p must be just after dnx, otherwise you won't be passing dnx the argument, as it is going to assume the -p argument will be for the actual command you're trying to run.